# Best way to clean up over-compressed audio with a clean sample in Audacity?

Tags: audio, compression, audacity, noise-cancelling

I have an audio file, which sounds a little muffled due to compression (it's not very bad however). I want to clean it up as much as possible with Audacity or similar (free) software. I have a high quality sample of other parts of that audio, can that help me in any way? Just noise reduction isn't doing much work, I figured maybe some program or effect can help by comparing two samples and finding out the difference.

So essentially I have two audio files, one is complete but in lower quality, one incomplete but in high quality, I'm trying to merge them and have the best quality possible.

Answer (score -1):

hard to say what is possible without more info about the audio files.
but creating the difference of two audios is easy. put both in 2 tracks and invert polarity of the compressed file. the resulting audio is the difference

Comment: That's not going to help with the problem at all, anyway, for now I found a better audio sample